# Error when trying to use @Spy Annotation: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "elementData" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am using the @Spy annotation and the following error appear when i'm trying to run the test:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "elementData" is null

This is the code i have:

```
package com.tddk.junit.service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class StudentServiceTest {
    @Spy
    List<String> spyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Test
    void whenUsingTheSpyAnnotation_thenObjectIsSpied() {
        spyList.add("one");
        spyList.add("two");

        verify(spyList).add("one");
        verify(spyList).add("two");

        assertThat(spyList).hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

The sample code above is from: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy I do exactly as the tutorial said but still getting an error. Can someone show me how to fix it please.

Comment: This is just an example, right? Because why would you spy on a list? And why would you verify that the method which you have just called, where called? There's usually no sense in doing `obj.method(); verify(obj).method();` – unless you don't trust the compiler/runtime … but we generally trust the compiler and runtime, don't we?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example. I'm new to unit testing. I came across the article and it gave me the example above. It doesn't explain much why I shouldn't spy on a list. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

This could be because you're using JDK 17 or plus, and the author of the article is using a lower JDK version.

After the JDK 17, more and more use cases are broken, and Spy is one of them. You can switch to the inline mockmaker to avoid this issue.

---

### Switching to the inline mockmaker

1. Create the `resources` directory inside the `test` directory.
2. Then Create a `mockito-extensions` directory within `resources` directory.
3. Create a file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` within `mockito-extensions` directory.
4. Finally, add this text `mock-maker-inline` to the `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file.

Folder structure should look like this:

[image: inline mockmaker folder structure]

Refer here as well: [Switch the default mockmaker to the inline mockmaker on JDK 17+](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2589)

---

Lastly, my advice is to not spy on lists, but instead perform checks on the real list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was desperate. My project is in Java 8 but my laptop was with Java 17. Thanks for your help.